# Removing lists containing some rules

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, scripting, rule

Consider a big list of lists of rules, namely

```
L={{Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1] - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1] - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1] - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> (-(Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2]) - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[w, 3] -> (-(Subscript[r, 3]*Subscript[w, 1]) - 
     Subscript[r, 2]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> 0, Subscript[c, 4] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 2] -> 0, Subscript[c, 5] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 3] -> 0, Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> -((Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> (-(Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2]) - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[w, 3] -> -((Subscript[r, 3]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> (-(Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2]) - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[w, 3] -> -((Subscript[r, 2]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> (-(Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1]) + 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> (-(Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1]) + 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (-(Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1]) + 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> -((Subscript[r, 3]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[r, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 2] -> (Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[c, 4] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> Subscript[c, 3], Subscript[c, 4] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 2] -> Subscript[c, 3], Subscript[c, 5] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 2] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1] - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1] - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 1] -> (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 1] - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[c, 4] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 2] -> ((Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2] + 
      Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])*Subscript[w, 1])/
    (Subscript[r, 1]*Subscript[r, 2]), Subscript[c, 3] -> 
   ((Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2] + Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])*
     Subscript[w, 1])/(Subscript[r, 1]*Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[c, 1] -> ((Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2] + 
      Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])*Subscript[w, 1])/
    (Subscript[r, 1]*Subscript[r, 2]), Subscript[c, 4] -> 
   (-(Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2]) - Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/
    Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[w, 2] -> 
   -((Subscript[r, 3]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[w, 3] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> -((Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> -((Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> (-(Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1]) + 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (-(Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1]) + 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> (-(Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1]) + 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 2], Subscript[c, 5] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 2] -> -((Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> -((Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[c, 1] -> -((Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> -((Subscript[r, 3]*Subscript[w, 1])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> (Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[r, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> (Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 2] - 
     Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> (Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 2] - 
     Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 2] - 
     Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 3], Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> (Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 2] - 
     Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> (Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 2] - 
     Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> (Subscript[c, 4]*Subscript[w, 2] - 
     Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 3], Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 2] -> -((Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 3]), 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> -((Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[r, 3]), 
  Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> Subscript[c, 3], Subscript[c, 2] -> Subscript[c, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> (Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[w, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> (Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[w, 1], 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[c, 3] -> Subscript[c, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> 0, Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 2] -> Subscript[c, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> Subscript[c, 1], Subscript[c, 4] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> 0, Subscript[c, 2] -> 0, Subscript[c, 3] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> (-(Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2]) - 
     Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, 
 {Subscript[c, 1] -> 0, Subscript[c, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> -((Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 2] -> 0, Subscript[c, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> 0, Subscript[c, 4] -> 
   (-(Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2]) - Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/
    Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 1] -> 0, Subscript[c, 3] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 4] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 1]), 
  Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 3] -> 0, Subscript[c, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> 0, Subscript[c, 4] -> 
   (-(Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[r, 2]) - Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/
    Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[w, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 3] -> 0, Subscript[c, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> -((Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[r, 3])/Subscript[r, 2]), 
  Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 1] -> Subscript[c, 2], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[c, 4] -> 
   (Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[w, 1], Subscript[c, 5] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 2] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 2] -> Subscript[c, 1], 
  Subscript[c, 3] -> Subscript[c, 1], Subscript[c, 4] -> 0, 
  Subscript[c, 5] -> (Subscript[c, 6]*Subscript[w, 2])/Subscript[w, 1], 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 3] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 1] -> Subscript[c, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> Subscript[c, 3], Subscript[c, 4] -> 
   (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[w, 2], Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, {Subscript[c, 1] -> Subscript[c, 3], 
  Subscript[c, 2] -> Subscript[c, 3], Subscript[c, 4] -> 
   (Subscript[c, 5]*Subscript[w, 3])/Subscript[w, 2], Subscript[c, 6] -> 0, 
  Subscript[w, 1] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, 
  Subscript[r, 1] -> 0}}
```

I would like to remove in `L` all lists containing at least one of the following rules : `Subscript[r, 2] -> 0`, `Subscript[r, 3] -> 0`, `Subscript[r, 1] -> 0`,
`Subscript[w, 3] -> 0`, `Subscript[w, 2] -> 0`, `Subscript[w, 1] -> 0`

what routine should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See links at the end for documentation links of Mathematica functions used in this answer.

---

One can use [`HoldPattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html):

```
Select[L, 
 FreeQ[HoldPattern[Subscript[x_, d_] -> 0] /; 
   MemberQ[{r, w}, x] && MemberQ[Range[3], d]]]
```

The pattern matching is particularly convenient for longer lists of cases to remove but one can already see a bit of the benefit with the code that directly lists the cases to remove

```
Select[L, 
 FreeQ[b_ /; 
   MemberQ[{Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, 
     Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, Subscript[w, 2] -> 0,
      Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, b]]]
```

---

Another comparison:

**Note :** the operator form of `MatchQ` is used below

```
DeleteCases[L, 
 a_ /; AnyTrue[a, 
   MatchQ[HoldPattern[Subscript[x_, d_] -> 0] /; 
     MemberQ[{r, w}, x] && MemberQ[Range[3], d]]]]
```

and

```
DeleteCases[L, 
 a_ /; AnyTrue[a, 
   MemberQ[{Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, 
      Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, 
      Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}, #] &]]
```

---

*Links below are generated automatically using Mathematica on the text of this answer. May contain errors.*

{[HoldPattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern.html),[Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html),[FreeQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html),[Subscript](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript.html),[MemberQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html),[Range](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Range.html),[MatchQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatchQ.html),[DeleteCases](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html),[AnyTrue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnyTrue.html)}

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like (unrolling for clarity)

```
Select[
  L, 
  Not@*
    ContainsAny[
      {Subscript[r, 2] -> 0, 
       Subscript[r, 3] -> 0, 
       Subscript[r, 1] -> 0, 
       Subscript[w, 3] -> 0, 
       Subscript[w, 2] -> 0, 
       Subscript[w, 1] -> 0}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `DeleteCases`:**

```
DeleteCases[L, {___, Subscript[(r | w), (1 | 2 | 3)] -> 0, ___}]
```

---

**Using `Position`:**

```
Extract[L, 
 Complement[Range[Length@L], 
  DeleteDuplicates@(First /@ 
     Position[L, Subscript[(r | w), (1 | 2 | 3)] -> 0])
  ]
 ]
```

---

Result:

$$\left\{\left\{c_1\to \frac{c_5 w_1-c_6 w_2}{r_1},c_2\to \frac{c_5 w_1-c_6 w_2}{r_1},c_3\to \frac{c_5 w_1-c_6 w_2}{r_1},c_4\to \frac{-c_5 r_2-c_6 r_3}{r_1},w_3\to \frac{-r_3 w_1-r_2 w_2}{r_1}\right\}\right\}$$