# Create a function that takes a symbol and searches wolfram documentation for the page and opens it

Tags: functions, documentation, web-access, hyperlink, webtools

This is way over my pay-grade, so I have no idea where to start. I'm certain MMA has some very good internet capabilities, so it seems to me that it is possible.

This is really a 2-part question:

1. How might one go about creating a `Hyperlink` function, by simply inputting a `Symbol` as an argument that takes you to the documentation page?
2. Is there a way of checking that the page actually exists before creating the link so that the link doesn't take you to an error page?

For example, finding and opening the main page for `Column` and `Frame` with the browser. If not possible, is it still possible to do this by opening MMA's own built-in documentation?

Comment: In Mathematica each built-in symbol has a tooltip that links to the documentation. Alternatively, highlight the symbol and press `F1` for help.

Comment: I made a function that searches for Mathematica functions in text and provides a list of links for each function it found. That is what I used to make the links [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/275530/86543) for example.

Comment: the code takes "example" as an input which is a copy pasted string (if a popup appears when pasting the string between "" say yes).

Comment: `notations = "@" | "//" | "/@" | "@@" | "@@@" | "@*" | "/*";
StringJoin["[", #, "]", 
    "(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/", #, ".html)"] & /@ 
  Select[example // TextWords // Map[StringSplit[#, notations] &] // 
     Flatten // 
    DeleteDuplicates, (NameQ["System`" <> #] && 
      Not[NumericQ[ToExpression@#]] &)] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: The only case where I saw it did not work was with formal names like `\[FormalX]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the symbol can be found in `Names`, two links are created: one each for local and online documentation. For some `System` names, a link may not always be present but it is rare. If the symbol is not readily found, a search button is generated for the input string that leads to a search page at the Wolfram site.

```
s = "Part"
If[MemberQ[Names["System`*"], s]
 , RowBox[{Hyperlink[Button["Local"], "paclet:ref/" <> s]
    , Hyperlink[Button["Online"], 
     "https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/" <> s <> ".html"]
    }] // DisplayForm
 , Hyperlink[Button["Search"], 
  "https://search.wolfram.com/?q=" <> s <> "&skip="]
 ]
```

You can experiment with this and turn it into a function as you see fit.

Comment: thank you so much this is perfect

Comment: Thanks for the accept. In addition, you can check out the `URLResponseTime` function for situations where a website is taking longer than expected to repond. Regards.

Comment: Very nice. OP might also want to consider `NameQ` for example `NameQ["Part"]`. `NameQ` also evaluates to `True` for formal characters like `\[FormalX]` and strangely `\[Mu]` but not other Greek letters like `\[Beta]`